# How to get the record without first record in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have Product and Product image models.
"Product" HasMany Product image.

Let's say I want to display the 2 product images of any Product without the first Image, how to do that?
I know the first could be retrieved like $product->productImage->first()... but how to retrieve the image records without the first image?

Comment: use skip(number) method to omit the record like $users = User::orderBy('xp', 'DESC')->skip(50)->get();

Answer (score 1):

You can use `skip(1)` function to skip first row from data as:

```
Attendance::skip(1)->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: This will not work on relationships

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like this

```
$productImages = product->productImage;
array_shift($productImages)
```

Now `$productImages` variable contains every image except for the first one.

I believe even if you have 100 thousand rows in your table, if you take one extra row (exactly **first row**), it changes nothing :D

Answer (score 0):

As per saying, the Product hasMany Product Images.

To retrieve the product images except first image, use `foreach($container as $item)`

> **If it's in the controller**

```
    $loop_iteraton = 1;
    foreach ($product->productImage as $image){
        if(!($loop_iteraton == 1)){
            echo $image;
        }
        $loop_iteraton++;
    }
```

> **If it's in the blade**

`@foreach ($product->productImage as $image){`
         `@if(!($loop->iteraton == 1)){`
               `echo $image;`
         `}`
         `@endif`
`}`
`@endforeach`

The above code snippets will show all images from expect the first image

if you want to get only the recent or latest image(only one) use the orderBy('created_at','DESC') on hasMany relationship in Product class i.e.

```
public function productImage(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

and use `$product->productImage->first();` wherever you want to read the image